# Wrong Localization for Translation in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm using TYPO3 with two languages but everytime i add a english translation it lands in the german localization. Is there anything i can do to fix this?

Regards,
justcasper

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Flux?

Comment: Yes i do. It just happens in fluid-elements.

Comment: So your Problem is probably a bug of flux instead of a TYPO3 bug.

Comment: seems like. i try to update to flux 9. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's the translation mode your two columns are in? Connected or Free mode? Also how do you create those content elements? Do you create them by clicking on Translate in the right column or are you trying to add them directly?

EDIT: Sorry I couldn't ask that as a comment to your question. This is not a solution, but I can't provide one with more context.

Comment: TBH i don't know the difference between connected and free mode. I Added a Picture how i created the translation.
I noticed that it just happens when i try to translate inside a fluid-element.

Comment: Have you tried using the translate button in the right column instead of using the create translation? Just in case Flux needs the info where to place the translation.